# Change Varbiable to be changed by input

Tags: python-3.x

I try to change the variable that will be changed by input. So if i call the function, i want to define the variable that will be changed by input. In one case variable "a" should be changed, in the other case i want to change variable "b".
Is there an option to change "test.a" in the function def calc?
To use check and change the variable by if request is not an option.

Thank you and best regards,
Carl

```
class test:
        
    a = 1
    b = 2
    
    def f(x):
        return test.a*x + test.b*x
      
    def calc(x,change):
        
        #change variable to be changed between "test.a" and "test.b" by input of "change"
        test.a = 10        
        solution = test.f(x)
        
        print(solution)        
        
        
test.calc(1,"b")
```

Comment: How do you check if you want to use `a` or `b`? Based on what condition? @Coarl

Comment: By calling test.calc(1,"a") or test.calc(1,"b").

Comment: It depends on whichh parameter should be under investigation

Comment: Why not use simple if-else condition

Comment: Because in my real programm i have 6 possible parameters and there are different thinks that will be changed by input. It would be possible but there will by many if-else conditions. And at least i tought that there is maybe a smoother solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setattr` function to accomplish this. After applying recommendations from my IDE, code looks like this:

```
class Test:
    a = 1
    b = 2

    @staticmethod
    def f(x):
        return Test.a * x + Test.b * x

    @staticmethod
    def calc(x, change):
        # change variable to be changed between "test.a" and "test.b" by input of "change"
        setattr(Test, change, x)

        # check class variables after the change
        print(Test.a)
        print(Test.b)

        solution = Test.f(x)

        print(solution)


Test.calc(1, "b")
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, that works perfect. I didnt knew this function.